# Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Angular - Meteor

Tags: angular, meteor

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token let at column 1 in [let option of questionForm.controls.Options.controls; index as j] in MultiplechoiceComponent@0:126 ("Form">  Options  ][ngFor]="let option of questionForm.controls.Options.controls; index as j">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Angular (not AngularJS) and TypeScript, try the following:

`*ngFor="let option of questionForm.controls.Options.controls; let j = index"`